# Как работает функция round в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, математика, round

Не очень понятно как работает round в Python.

```
a = 25.455
 
print(a, round(a, 1))

b = 25.45


print(b, round(b, 1))
```

Comment: На самом деле проблема не в округлении, а в том, что числа с плавающей точкой неточны и `25.45` в на самом деле хранится в памяти как `25.4499999999999992894...` — и соответственно оно округляется до `25.4`

Comment: (у меня такое чувство, что я недавно уже видел подобный вопрос, но не могу найти)

Comment: Подобный [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/646263/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-round-%d0%b2-python-%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f) был, хоть и не так уж недавно)

Comment: Возможно этот: [Ошибка округления Python и Linux](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1450297)

Comment: @Павел, тот вопрос про другое: числа могут быть представлены точно, но округляются в разных направлениях. В этом числа не могут быть представлены точно, неточность влияет на округление.